# excel: Index and macth formula that will pull the whole row of data from the match.

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am creating a template at work. Columns A through H are used. Workers will calculate the charging for a court order but the court order can move between case numbers. So column A is each case number and then column D and E are the dates it was charging on that case number. The case number can be repeated in column A because it can start charging on case 123 then switch to 456 and back to 123. 
Workers need to key the charging from beginning to end.

In a separate area:
I need the worksheet to then take that data and choose the unique case numbers in column A and list each row with data for each case number together . Almost like sort the data based on column A first and then column D- exactly how the sort feature would work and list it.

I already have a formula that creates the unique list and that totals all the charges for each unique case but I have not been able to find anything to get this sorted type listing. I have tried several index and match formulas.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer with step-by-step instructions.**

Refer to this image:

[image]

Step 1: Select G3:G13. Paste the following formula into the formula bar and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to commit the formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SMALL($A$3:$A$13,COLUMN(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA($A$3:$A$13)))))
```

(Excel will place curly braces { } around the formula in the formula editor to indicate that it is an array formula.)

Step 2: Select J3:J13. Paste the following formula into the formula bar and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to commit the formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SMALL($A$3:$A$13*1000000+$D$3:$D$13,COLUMN(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA($A$3:$A$13)))))-TRANSPOSE(SMALL($A$3:$A$13,COLUMN(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA($A$3:$A$13))))*1000000)
```

Format J3:J13 as dates.

Step 3: Select H3. Paste the following formula into the formula bar and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to commit the formula:

```
=INDEX(B$3:B$13,MATCH("TRUETRUE",($G3=$A$3:$A$13)&($J3=$D$3:$D$13),0))
```

Step 4: Copy H3 into the rest of the cells in columns H, I, and K. Format column K as dates.

Comment: I was not babe to get either of those to work. The second one is more what I am going for. it just shows the formula in each cell I even changed the word casenumbers to case which is the header of the column and it still didn't work. if i keep casenumber i get #name and #name? errors

Comment: Also won't transpose make my horizontal data vertical? I am not trying to do that.

Comment: this formula will give me the unique case numbers but it doesn't help me if they repeat plus I need it to list all 7 columns not just column A. I need it to match all the like case numbers in column A and list them together but also have all the data from column b-h vlookup is not where i want to go either.                                                       =IFERROR(INDEX($A$5:$A$30, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$47:A47, $A$5:$A$30), 0)),"")

Comment: It's an array formula, so don't type in the braces { }. Excel will add the braces to the formula editor after you commit the formula as an array formula (ctrl+shift+enter).

Comment: SMALL will return a horizontal array, so TRANSPOSE converts it back to vertical.

Comment: Updated with step-by-step. Should be easier to follow.